# Кортежи. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, структуры-данных

Зачем нужны кортежи в питоне? Защита от дурака? Я, конечно, понимаю, что люди есть разные, могут творить всякую хрень. Но, если я создаю некоторый объект и подразумеваю, что менять его не собираюсь, значит я не буду его менять. Смысл для блокировки вводить новый объект?

Comment: [Похожий вопрос в английской версии SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174124/why-do-we-need-tuples-in-python-or-any-immutable-data-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кортежи - это неизменяемые объекты и он имеет ряд преимуществ.

Кортеж может использоваться, например, для хранения информации о подключении к БД и скорость работы с кортежем быстрее, чем, например, со списком. И быстрее он работает как раз потому, что неизменяемый.

Кортеж, также, занимает меньше памяти, что может быть полезно, если речь идет о большим объемах данных.

Практические примеры могут быть самыми разнообразными, я приведу простые.

Если вы пользуетесь выражениями-геренаторами, то выражение будет быстрее работать с кортежем, чем со списком.

```
numbers = (1,2,3,4,5)
squares_under_10 = (number*number for number in numbers if number*number < 10)
```

Для того, чтобы убедиться в этом, можно воспользоваться [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

```
$ python -m timeit '(number*number for number in [1,2,3,4,5])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.591 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '(number*number for number in (1,2,3,4,5))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.472 usec per loop
```

На небольших объемах данных это может быть незаметно, однако если итерируемых значений много, то выгода становится заметной.

*Под звездочкой я обозначу один момент.

Если в кортеж положить список, то вы сможете его изменить:

```
T = ([1,2,3], 4, 5, 6);
T[0][0] = 10;
print(T[0][0])
#выведет 10
```

Тут вы меняете список внутри кортежа, но не сам кортеж. При этом вы не сможете удалить первый (нулевой) элемент кортежа или заменить его на другой тип данных.

Это имеет ряд преимуществ, когда вам необходима конкретная структура данных (неизменяемая), с заданным набором элементов, но при этом некоторые объекты внутри кортежа могут меняться в процессе работы (напр., список).

Comment: Могли бы Вы замерить время работы с кортежем и без него, как это сделано в английской версии? Тогда поставлю "Правильный ответ"

Comment: @hedgehogues обновил ответ

Comment: squares_under_10 это не кортеж, а генератор, и скорось его выполнения может быть медленнее списка

Comment: @vadimvaduxa Все верно, но numbers - кортеж

Answer (score 2):

Перевод ответа с [английского стека](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174124/why-do-we-need-tuples-in-python-or-any-immutable-data-type):

> 1. Неизменяемые объекты позволяют производить существенную оптимизацию;
>      Это, по-видимому, аналогично неизменяемым строкам в Java,
>      разработанным совершенно отдельно, но примерно в то же время, что и
>      Python, и почти все является неизменным в действительно
>      функциональных языках.
> 2. В Python, в частности, только неизменяемые могут быть хешируемыми (и, следовательно, членами множеств или ключами в словарях). Опять
>      же, это позволяет производить серьёзные оптимизации. Создание же
>      приличных хеш-таблиц, хранящих полностью изменяемые объекты,
>      является кошмаром - либо вы берете копии всего, чего только есть,
>      либо Вы замучаетесь проверять, изменение хеша объекта с момента
>      последней ссылалки на него. Пример проблемы оптимизации:
>
>    $ python -mtimeit '["fee", "fie", "fo", "fum"]' loops, best of 3: 0.432 usec per
>
>    $ python -mtimeit '("fee", "fie", "fo", "fum")' loops, best of 3: 0.0563 usec per loop

Comment: стоит упомянуть о распространённом соглашении: [_"Tuples are for heterogeneous data, list are for homogeneous data.
Tuples are **not** read-only lists."_](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-March/033964.html)